# Does Ubuntu run on current Asus Transformer Prime?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've read instructions about dual boot Android / Transformer Prime (a significant factor in ordering one).
Also about not working with /latest/ Transformer Prime (firmware / BIOS?)
Also about imminent Ubuntu ARM support.

Will I be able to run Ubuntu in a day or two when Transformer arrives?

Also, am I right to assume I can restore Transformer to factory status if I break something in the attempt?

Comment: Please, use the search function.

Comment: Transformer and Transformer Prime are two different models.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu on the Transformer Prime is not stable at this time. Since Asus released an unlocking tool it is possible to install Ubuntu. But not all drivers work and no easy way to install it.

You can run Ubuntu on just about any Android device using VNC to a chroot'ed session but performance is very poor.

You could follow the latest at
http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1411

I for one can't wait, I'm very happy with Ubuntu on my Asus Transformer (tf101)